# Can one predict the histogram $H(f)$ of some time series $f(t)$?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

Say I am measuring a continuous signal and have a time series $f(t)$ with a known expression (for example, a Gaussian wave packet) between some $t_1,t_2$ , is there a way to compute the histogram function $H(f)$ (or $P(f))$ without using manual computation like the "hist" function? Or at least predict its asymptotic behavior?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a histogram with fixed bins, the histogram is fully determined from the time-series by the counts of the number of outcomes within each bin at the relevant time points $t_1,...,t_n$.  Consequently, "predicting the histogram" is equivalent to predicting the number of outcomes of the time-series that will fall within the relevant range of each bin.  If you are able to use your time-series model to estimate the predictive distributions for the outcomes then you can turn these into estimated probabilities for falling into each bin.  With sufficient work you could then get a prediction of the count vector that would arise from counting which points fall within each bin.

As a final observation, it is worth noting that if you are talking about a histogram where the bin boundaries depend on the data then things become *much* more complicated.  In this latter case the histogram would be determined by counts of points in bins whose ranges are themselves determined by the overall pattern of the outcomes.  This latter problem would be extremely complex and it is likely that it could only fruitfully be analysed by simulation methods.